# Rails : How to merge or join two active record collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, plsql, rails-activerecord

In my customer controller I have two collection as follows:

The first one is to get a collection of Customers where the expiryDate column is having a valid date, as follows :

```
@customer_with_expirydate = Customer.where.not(expiryDate: nil)
```

The second one is to get a collection of Customers where the expiryDate column is nil or nnot present, as follows :

```
@customer_no_expirydate = Customer.where(expiryDate: nil)
```

Now I want to display the combined result of these two collection into a table structure, here one condition is like after listing all customers with expiryDate only customers without expiry need to be listed.

I need something like the following:

@all_customers = @customer_with_expirydate + @customer_no_expirydate

The important thing is that customers without expiry should be appended last.

Comment: I can't remember which way it'll work but rather than do two queries, just do one and order by expiry date.  `@all_customers = Customer.order(expiry_date: :desc)`  it might need to be ascending for the ones without an expiry date to be last though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Praveen Answer you had already given:

```
@all_customers = @customer_with_expirydate + @customer_no_expirydate
```

Returns All customers who has expiry date and then customers who does not have expiry date.

similarly:

```
@all_customers = @customer_no_expirydate + @customer_with_expirydate
```

Returns All customers who does not have expiry date and then customers who has expiry date.

```
Then you can loop @all_customers inside the table.
```

And if you can use only one query for this, then you should use:

```
@all_customers = Customer.order(expiryDate: :desc)
```

Answer (score 3):

How about doing something simple with just one query? Something like:

```
@all_customers = Customer.order(expiryDate: :desc)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let sort the customers by db query, it is more efficient than using array appending:

```
@ordered_customers = Customer.order('expiryDate DESC NULLS LAST')
```

So the customer with `expiryDate = nil` will be at the end of your result!

Comment: Thanks dude let me try on this one :)